# How do I programmatically save "2019-11-04 07:30:00+01"?

Tags: datetime

I have "2019-11-04 07:30:00+01" as datetime value. I am not getting how to handle  the `"+1"` part in a Drupal 8 date field.

I am using this code, but it's not giving me any value.

```
use Drupal\Core\Datetime;

$userTimezone = new DateTimeZone(drupal_get_user_timezone());
$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
$myDateTime = new DateTime($item['start_date'], $gmtTimezone);
print_r($myDateTime);
die;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `DateTime` class in `Drupal\Core\Datetime` you should use `DrupalDateTime` class instead try with.

```
    use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
   //$userTimezone = new DateTimeZone(drupal_get_user_timezone());
    $gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
    $myDateTime = new DrupalDateTime($item['start_date'], $gmtTimezone);
    $dateTime = $myDateTime->getPhpDateTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three errors in that code:

1. `use` requires the fully qualified name of a class, not its namespace.
2. Drupal doesn't have any `Drupal\Core\Datetime` class. There is the [`Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DrupalDateTime.php/class/DrupalDateTime/8.8.x) class, which is the class you want to use.
3. The second argument of the constructor of `DrupalDateTime` isn't necessary since, as the documentation for [`DrupalDateTime::__construct()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DrupalDateTime.php/function/DrupalDateTime%3A%3A__construct/8.8.x) says, it's not used when the string passed as first argument specifies a timezone.

   > **mixed `$timezone`**: PHP DateTimeZone object, string or `NULL` allowed. Defaults to `NULL`. Note that the `$timezone` parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the `$time` parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00). @see http://php.net/manual/datetime.construct.php

The code you should use is then the following one.

```
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;

$myDateTime = new DrupalDateTime($item['start_date']);
```

The code you are using doesn't return any value because you are using a class that doesn't exist. It should raise an error, as the code is referring a class that PHP cannot find.

As side note, the `DrupalDateTime` class should be used when a class, a method, or a function requires an instance of that class, you need a class that is more flexible than the `DateTime` class, or you need one of the methods that Drupal extends, for example [`DrupalDateTime::format()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DrupalDateTime.php/function/DrupalDateTime%3A%3Aformat/8.8.x).
In the other cases, you should use the `DateTime` class implemented in PHP.

See also the documentation for [`DateTimePlus`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Datetime%21DateTimePlus.php/class/DateTimePlus/8.8.x), which makes the difference between the PHP class and the Drupal classes clearer.

> This class wraps the PHP `DateTime` class with more flexible initialization parameters, allowing a date to be created from an existing date object, a timestamp, a string with an unknown format, a string with a known format, or an array of date parts. It also adds an errors array and a `__toString()` method to the date object.
>
> This class is less lenient than the `DateTime` class. It changes the default behavior for handling date values like '2011-00-00'. The `DateTime` class would convert that value to '2010-11-30' and report a warning but not an error. This extension treats that as an error.
>
> As with the `DateTime` class, a date object may be created even if it has errors. It has an errors array attached to it that explains what the errors are. This is less disruptive than allowing datetime exceptions to abort processing. The calling script can decide what to do about errors using [`hasErrors()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Datetime%21DateTimePlus.php/function/DateTimePlus%3A%3AhasErrors/8.8.x) and [`getErrors()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Datetime%21DateTimePlus.php/function/DateTimePlus%3A%3AgetErrors/8.8.x).